# Append a String variable in a file

Tags: scripting

I want to append a string variable.
for e.g. WINDOW=WINDOW winName="fp_w_RetrocessionTrigger" winTitle="Retrocession Trigger" comp="FPGUI" funcId="14316" domainId="bancs" preLoad="true">
This is my string variable(WINDOW). I want this varible of string get append in another file using sed or awk cmd.

Although I have tried the cmd like sed -i ''$n'i "'$WINDOW'"' test.xml but it only prints space there. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, however if u want to append a text in the beginning and/or at the end of each line of a file, you can try the below

```
$ cat 1.txt
1
2
3
4
5
```

Add the text in the beginning of the line :

```
$ sed -e 's/^/start_of_the_line/' -i 1.txt
```

Add the text at the end of the line :

```
$ sed -e 's/$/end_of_the_line/' -i 1.txt
```

Output

```
$cat 1.txt
start_of_the_line1end_of_the_line
start_of_the_line2end_of_the_line
start_of_the_line3end_of_the_line
start_of_the_line4end_of_the_line
start_of_the_line5end_of_the_line
```